# How to search for the amount of times an element appears in a list in scheme using recursion

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

The question is asking to count how many times e appears in a list of integers:  (count e L)

Here is what I have so far.. (I obviously know its incorrect)

```
(define count(lambda(e L)
           (cond
             ((null? L)         0)
             ((= e (car L))    (e(cdr L)))
             (#t (count(e(cadr L))))
)))
```

Any ideas??

Comment: I've made a correction to the one line, (#t        (count (cdr L)))                                   I still cannot figure out what will go in the line above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, here's a corrected version:

```
(define count
  (lambda (e L)
    (cond
      ((null? L)     0)
      ((= e (car L)) (+ 1 (count e (cdr L))))
      (else          (count e (cdr L))))))
```

Please notice:

- The way you're passing parameters to `count` is wrong
- The correct way to advance a recursion over a list is by calling `cdr`, not `cadr`
- You forgot to call `count` in the second case
- The last case should be handled using `else`, not `#t`

Answer (score 0):

The critical step you're missing is when you *do* find the value:  you need to return

```
plus(1 count(e(cdr L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `named let` with recursion may help clarify the process:

```
(define (counte L e)
  (let loop ((L L)        ; start with full list
             (c 0))       ; and 0 as count
    (cond
      [(empty? L) c]      ; if end reached, return count
      [(equal? e (car L)) ; if first item equals e
       (loop (cdr L)      ; loop with rest of list and incremented count
             (add1 c))]
      [else
       (loop (cdr L)      ; else loop with rest of list without incrementing count
             c)]
      )))
```